# SQL Server login error over ODBC connection

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, odbc, ms-access-2007, database-administration

I'm working on a project using `SQL Server 2012` and I am running into an issue while attempting to update a `login`.

I was attempting to add DDL permissions to a `login` and when I went to hit `OK` and close the properties window, I received this error.

[image: SQL Server Error]

I closed the `login` properties window and reopened it to find that the `login`'s database role changes had indeed been updated to reflect the changes I made.

It looked to me like my changes had been committed, and **then** this error popped up.

I went to connect over an `ODBC` connection I had made earlier for the same login, but discovered I no longer could, I was getting this error from the `ODBC`.

[image: ODBC Error]

I know for a fact that this `ODBC` connection was working for this login at some point before my changes since I had a linked table that was using this same connection. It was able to both pull down updates from the `SQL Server` and push through changes back up to the server level.

Can anyone help shed some light onto what a solution to these errors may be? I assumed they were related since they both began occurring this morning, but I'm not positive of that fact. My database administrator is out of the office till tomorrow, so I'd really like to get this resolved before then.

This is what I get when I try to use that logon through `SSMS`

[image: SSMS logon]

Comment: Dumb question, but can you log in through SSMS? Also, you may get some better answers at the [DBA SE](http://dba.stackexchange.com).

Comment: not dumb at all, I've updated my question with an image of the error I get when I try to use SSMS with that logon.

Comment: I'm just grasping at straws to try and troubleshoot here; I don't know the actual errors. But are you trying to log in using Windows authentication or SQL authentication? Check the login properties to make sure the login did not get disabled with that initial error, and that you're logging in against the appropriate authentication (Windows vs SQL authentication).

Comment: The logon is still there and both the ODBC and SQL Server Installation are using SQL Server Authentication. I'll double check whether I accidentally disabled it.

Comment: Nice job, turns out `granting` permission to access the database engine is helpful for when you want to `query` the database. Don't know how i turned that one off. If you put it down as an answer, I'll choose it.

Comment: Great! Glad you got it resolved. I'll throw something into an answer, but you don't have to mark it as an answer if you would prefer to wait and see if somebody can give a better answer (ideally with an explanation of what happened after that first error).

Comment: For a pure `SQL` problem I would leave it open, but `ms-access` issues rarely get full answers. This may get lucky and a `dba` tag trawler will pick it up if it looks interesting. Your answer is good enough for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm putting this into an answer, since it solved OP's problem. I don't know what happened during/after the initial error (when granting DDL permission), nor exactly what the other errors were pointing to.

Because the user was unable to login through ODBC or SSMS, the first step would be to check the user and login properties in SSMS, to ensure that, for example, it is enabled, and that it was granted permission to the database.

In the comments, OP found that the user was not setup with `GRANT`.

Comment: The user feels very dumb about this.